# how to get custom google sign-in link in php symfony2

Tags: php, google-signin, google-api-client, symfony-2.8

I am trying to googlesign in with

[Connect with Google+](https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?redirect_uri=http://bv.gplus.com/web/app_dev.php/gplus/&response_type=code&client_id=XXXXXclient-idXXXe.apps.googleusercontent.com&scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login+https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email&access_type=offline)

after redirection in my system not able to get google id, email, etc information 
please help me out

follow code i am using but not working on me

```
 $gClient = new \Google_Client(array('client_id'=>'XX.apps.googleusercontent.com', 'client_secret' => 'XXXXXXXX'));

 if($_GET['code']) {

 $token = $gClient->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($_GET['code']);
 $result = json_decode( $gClient->authorize('https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/userinfo' ), true );
 $message = 'Your unique Google user id is: ' . $result['id'] . ' and your name is ' . $result['name'];
    echo $message. "<br/>";
}
```

above code note working for me

Comment: please add the relevant code.

Comment: updated with code i need userinfo after login success.